# Is there a way to increase mouse scroll speed on ubuntu 18.04 Xorg

Tags: xorg, mouse

I have tried to modify the libinput by adding my own .hwdb for a mouse to increase the scroll per degree from 15 to 30 but it did not seem to take effect.

```
# MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
mouse:*:name:MOSART Semi. 1.4G Wireless Mouse:
MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE=30
```

Is there any way to make the mouse scroll faster, globally not just under firefox (i know i could about:something blah blah change it there) but i need it under libre office, chrome, terminal, vscode, gimp etc i cannot work with this few scrolls per click.

I am willing to follow any instruction that is thorough upto and including modifying system files and kernel settings if necessary or replacing or modifying drivers (so long as instructions are sufficiently clear)

Thanks in advance,

ask any questions and i will update this question to provide any information you want, for a start:

I am apparantly under Xorg not Wayland and have anyway used dpkg-divert to make sure that it is impossible to login to a wayland enabled session, echoing $DISPLAY or $WAYLAND_DISPLAY confirms that wayland is not enabled.

I am using a mouse with a wireless dongle, it appears under xinput 3 times, once under pointer and twice under keyboards, this is because it has a back a forward and a windows key.

ubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade from 17.10 via forced upgrade flag (my choice)

wireless mouse with dongle - detected as MOSART semi 2.4g Wireless Mouse

HP Spectre x360 15 inch 2015 model

intel core i7 6500u

16gb ram

ssd

intel 520 graphics card built into the skylake chipset, no secondary

4k screen running at 1080p

Comment: See https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?314578-Fedora-25-Mouse-Scroll-Speed and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351395/modify-mouse-wheel-and-touchpad-two-finger-scrolling-speed/352099#352099

Comment: Moving to xorg would mean you are not on wayland and so you would not be increasing scroll speed under wayland.

Comment: True, but if that's the only answer for someone under Wayland... To not be under Wayland... then that works as an answer

Comment: @DavidMcGowan - IMHO you should file a bug report against Wayland and fall back to Xorg

Comment: You aren't "forced" to upgrade 17.10 to 18.04 it is "offered". 16.04 users are offered an upgrade to 18.04.1 after July 26, 2018. Any new update you can consider performing on a test partition before committing. With major upgrades this is 10 times more important.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix when i say forced, i mean that i use a forced flag with the update to force my 17.10 to upgrade to 18.04 not that I personally was forced

Comment: Oh sorry for reading that wrong.

Comment: @Panther ive tried falling back to Xorg by changing the .conf under /etc/gdm3/ but echoing $DESKTOP_SESSION still shows ubuntu (which i believe means wayland)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thats ok, i can see how it might sound like i am now upset after the update, wheras i was on wayland anyway under 17.10 and just didnt use a mouse just the trackpad, but this is now my daily driver so...

Comment: @DavidMcGowan to see what you are using use `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY` and / or `echo $DISPLAY` I get `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY
wayland-0` At any rate, I am sorry you are having this problem, but if it is not working on xorg either -> bug report for sure.

Comment: @panther hmm if I echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY I get a blank line and echo $DISPLAY i get :1

Comment: @DavidMcGowan if `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY` gives a blank line -> you are using Xorg (or you are in a console / ssh connection , etc). If you are using wayland you will get the wayland display returned, ie `wayland-0`